# Concatenate string with different alias name for each value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I am getting string like this from sql query
`[FY20-Q1],[FY20-Q2],[FY20-Q3],[FY20-Q4]`

I want to make the output as below
`[FY20-Q1] as currentQuater,[FY20-Q2] as nextQuater,[FY20-Q3] as nextQuater1,[FY20-Q4] as nextQuater2`

Note-The above format is coming from this query

```
select @cols = COALESCE (@cols+',['+period+']','['+period+']')
from fn_somefnname()
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The string you are getting literally has commas in it like that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Acutally I have table valued function which returns fiscal quaters only,I am using 
 Select @cols= COALESCE (@cols+',['+period+']','['+period+']') from fn_somefnname().If I could get data here in 2nd format that would also be fine.@JNevill

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: "Quarter" would be the English spelling.

Comment: Can you provide sample output of `fn_somefnname()`?